# Accessing a passed block in Ruby

Tags: ruby, block

I have a method that accepts a block, lets call it outer. It in turn calls a method that accepts another block, call it inner.

What I would like to have happen is for outer to call inner, passing it a new block which calls the first block.

Here's a concrete example:

```
class Array
  def delete_if_index
    self.each_with_index { |element, i| ** A function that removes the element from the array if the block passed to delete_if_index is true }
  end
end

['a','b','c','d'].delete_if_index { |i| i.even? }
  => ['b','d']
```

the block passed to delete_if_index is called by the block passed to each_with_index.

Is this possible in Ruby, and, more broadly, how much access do we have to the block within the function that receives it?

Comment: I think I know what you mean, but it might be helpful if you could show some pseudocode that does what you would like to be able to do. When you talk about receiving a block, do you mean literally a Block as in the Ruby language structure or do you mean a Closure?

Comment: You can wrap a block within another block. Does that work for you?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I've added a concrete example. I suspect I may be being a little wrongheaded about this, but it would still be interesting to know.

Comment: Modifying the block was clearly the wrong solution, but I can access it by explicitly assigning it to a variable, and it will remain within scope for any nested blocks I create. If no-one has any objections, I will modify the original question slightly to reflect this.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed for all your answers.

Answer (score 5):

You can wrap a block in another block:

```
def outer(&block)
  if some_condition_is_true
    wrapper = lambda {
      p 'Do something crazy in this wrapper'
      block.call # original block
    }
    inner(&wrapper)
  else
    inner(&passed_block)
  end
end

def inner(&block)
  p 'inner called'
  yield
end

outer do
  p 'inside block'
  sleep 1
end
```

I'd say opening up an existing block and changing its contents is Doing it Wrong<sup>TM</sup>, maybe continuation-passing would help here? I'd also be wary of passing around blocks with side-effects; I try and keep lambdas deterministic and have actions like deleting stuff in the method body. In a complex application this will likely make debugging a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the example is poorly chosen, but your concrete example is the same as:

```
[1,2,3,4].reject &:even?
```

Opening up and modifying a block strikes me as code smell. It'd be difficult to write it in a way that makes the side effects obvious.

Given your example, I think a combination of higher order functions will do what you're looking to solve.

**Update**: It's not the same, as pointed out in the comments. `[1,2,3,4].reject(&:even?)` looks at the contents, not the index (and returns [1,3], not [2,4] as it would in the question). The one below is equivalent to the original example, but isn't vary pretty.

```
[1,2,3,4].each_with_index.reject {|element, index| index.even? }.map(&:first)
```

Comment: That was a poor example. Assume the array doesn't contain numbers: ['a','b','c','d','e','f'] should return ['b','d','f'].

Comment: Maybe not the nicest oneliner, but: ['a','b','c','d','e','f'].each_with_index.reject{|letter, i| i.even?}.map(&:first)

Comment: I think this only works in 1.8.7 and later. #each_with_index returns an Enumerator if it's called without a block.

Answer (score 0):

So here's a solution to my own question. The passed in block is implicitly converted into a proc which can be received with the & parameter syntax. The proc then exists inside the closure of any nested block, as it is assigned to a local variable in scope, and can be called by it:

```
class Array
  def delete_if_index(&proc)
    ary = []
    self.each_with_index { |a, i| ary << self[i] unless proc.call(i) }
    ary
  end
end

[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10].delete_if_index {|index| index.even?}

  => [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

Here the block is converted into a proc, and assigned to the variable proc, which is then available within the block passed to each_with_index.