# Can a Ruby method access the implicit block argument?

Tags: ruby, closures, block

The implicit block argument passed to a Ruby method can be executed using `yield`, or its existence can be checked using `block_given?`. I'm trying to procify this implicit block to pass it to another method.

Is this possible?

(It's access to the implicit block argument I'm asking about. Replacing this with an explicit argument won't cut it.)

Comment: Taking into account my comment on Stefan's answer, I'm curious on why exactly do you reject to specify an explicit block argument?

Comment: @HolgerJust  I didn't give context to my question to avoid clogging it up, so here it is: you can't pass procs blindly around without the risk of a `return` in the proc leading to a jump error. I use Ruby in teaching OOP, and of course newbies learn blocks long before they fully grasp procs&lambdas, and I wondered did Ruby make it hard to get a reference to the implicit block argument for this reason? The answers here have been very useful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to the block argument via [`Proc.new`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Proc.html#method-c-new). From the docs:

> `::new` may be called without a block only within a method with an attached block, in which case that block is converted to the `Proc` object.

Example:

```
def bar
  yield * 2
end

def foo
  bar(&Proc.new)
end

foo(123)
#=> 456
```

Note that `Proc.new` raises an `ArgumentError` when called without passing a block.

Comment: While this works (TIL), you should still generally add an explicitly named block argument to the method signature if at all possible – it is still optional to pass a block in any case. With an explicitly named block however, you are also documenting that you expect and intend to use a block in the method. With Ruby >= 2.5, this also [hasn't much overhead anymore](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/14045) since the block is only lazily wrapped into a Proc when it is actually used (which is specifically not the case when you just pass it on to another method).

Comment: @HolgerJust of course, but the OP explicitly asked for it. (maybe to debug an existing method?)

Comment: @HolgerJust I'm very into explicit contracts, but your advice re explicitly named blocks seems to run against the spirit of the language, which encourages implicit block passing.

Comment: @ComDubh Ruby encourages simplicity. The right approach depends on the context. You should use an implicit block and `yield` if you are just going to call it. But if you are passing the block to another method, an explicit block argument is much simpler.

Comment: Stefan, I was replying @HolgerJust's remark re preferring an explicit block *in the general case*. I completely agree with what you wrote, it is HolgerJust's remark you are disagreeing with 

Comment: @ComDubh oh I see :-) This is probably a matter of taste. To me, it's just a syntax quirk occasionally needed to reference the block within the method – I don't add it when it's not needed. Actually, I never understood why you have to define and name a method's block argument. That only makes sense if there can be multiple blocks or if it would make the block mandatory – something that Ruby doesn't support. A pre-defined `block` keyword would've been much simpler.

Comment: @ComDubh Still, if you need a reference to a passed block, people reading your code will hate you a lot less if you use the very syntax element provided for that (i.e. a `&block` parameter) rather than applying some implicit magic to emulate it. If you don't need a named reference, just go ahead and use `yield`; nothing wrong with that. For Ruby < 2.5, if you defined a `&block` parameter, every passed block was wrapped into a Proc which is comparatively slow. This was quite an incentive to avoid block arguments. As Ruby is smarter now, it's likely a better idea to go the easy way.

Comment: @HolgerJust Isn't the `&block` syntax a hack? It looks like poor interface design. It occupies precious real estate in a parameter list, but it isn't a normal parameter. It tells the client nothing, just hints that the method asks the block something, e.g. checks its arity. That `Proc.new` procifies the block argument is a detail, but it's not "implicit magic" -- it's clearly documented. I guess Ruby folk are used to the `&block` syntax, which supports your pov. Stefan's idea of `block` keyword is appealing, but I guess not provided as the block isn't intended to be accessed in normal use.

Answer (score 5):

You can procify it, and more importantly *give it a name so you can reference it*, using the [`&` ampersand unary prefix sigil in the parameter list of the method](https://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Block+Argument), like so:

```rb
#implicit, anonymous, cannot be referenced:
def foo
  yield 23 if block_given?
end

foo {|i| puts i }
# 23

#explicit, named, can be referenced:
def bar(&blk)
  yield 23 if block_given? # still works

  blk.(42) if blk # but now it also has a name and is a `Proc`

  # since we have the block available as an object, we can inspect it
  p blk.arity, blk.parameters, blk.source_location, blk.binding

  b = blk.binding
  p b.local_variables.map {|var| [var, b.local_variable_get(var)] }.to_h
end

quux = "Hello"

bar { |a, b, c = nil, d: nil, &e| puts a }
# 23
# 42
# 2
# [[:opt, :a], [:opt, :b], [:opt, :c], [:key, :d], [:block, :e]]
# ["(irb)", 24]
# #<Binding:0x00007fb091051308>
# { :quux => "Hello" }
```

Those are your two choices:

- implicit, anonymous, not an object
- explicit, named, [`Proc`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Proc.html)

There used to be an undocumented trick that was actually an unintended side-effect of how `Proc::new` was implemented in MRI: `Proc::new` did not check whether you passed a block or not, it simply *assumed* that you passed a block and would take the first block off the top of the internal VM stack. So, if you didn't pass a block to `Proc::new`, it would actually end up creating a `Proc` for the implicit block that was passed to the method (since that was the one which just happened to be on the top of the stack).

But, that was never portable, never guaranteed, never worked in all Ruby implementations, and AFAIK no longer works in YARV.

Comment: This isn't answering my question at all. I want to procify the *implicit block argument*. What do I apply & to? I suspect this simply isn't possible.

Comment: This *is* the way of procifying the block argument. It's not quite clear what you want. You cannot do anything useful with a block because it is not an object. And you cannot do anything useful with an anonymous argument because you can't talk about it. The `&` parameter is the language feature in Ruby that allows you to a) name a block and b) make it an object. If you want to name a block and make it an object *and* not use the very language feature whose purpose it is to do exactly that, then you have to be more specific about *why* you don't want to use the language feature that does …

Comment: … what you need.

Comment: Your edit re Proc::new is interesting and relevant -- I was wondering what hack might be possible. I wrote in my question "It's access to the implicit block argument I'm asking about. Replacing this with an explicit argument won't cut it." Matthew Hinea's answer above hits the nail on the head.

Comment: Looks like the "undocumented trick" you referred is now documented behaviour. See Stefan's answer. This really answers my question.

Comment: @ComDubh maybe I'm missing something, but it seems to been [documented since 1.8.6](https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.6/Proc.html#method-c-new). The behavior of `Proc.new` without a block is also documented in the language specs. (I only have a 2010 JIS draft, not the current ISO version) @JörgWMittag do you know a Ruby implementation not supporting this?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7471166/6432429). In your case it would be something like:

```rb
def outer
  wrapper = lambda { |something|
    p 'Do something crazy in this wrapper'
    yield(something)
  }
  other_method(&wrapper)
end

def other_method
  yield(5)
end

outer { |x| puts x + 3 }
```

With that you get:

```rb
"Do something crazy in this wrapper"
8
=> nil
```

Comment: Wow! Great answer. I didn't think of closing over the `yield`.

Comment: This doesn't work if the `other_method` needs to know the arity of the block. Or, really anything about the block at all, such as its `source_location`.

Comment: Good point! This answer works for me, but I'm not 100% happy because it's still not a procifying of the implicit block the method receives. I'm guessing the language designers didn't want to permit blocks to be passed around as misuse can easily lead to a `LocalJumpError`.